# Arquivo html não identifica CSS

Tags: html, css

Fui por um estilo na página e o HTML não usa o arquivo CSS.
Primeiro coloquei assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
```

E no console dava esta mensagem:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
> text/html: "http://localhost:4000/main.css".

Então coloquei: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">` e continuava dando a mesma mensagem.

Troquei para `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="bootstrap.css">` e a mensagem parou de dart no console, mas meus stylos não funcionam, é como se eu não tivesse chamando nada, e os arquivos estão na mesma pasta da index.
O que pode ser?

************ Atualizações ***********

Conforme pediram, segue código do servidor:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(server);
var fs = require('fs');

function server(req, response){
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('view/index.html'));
};

http.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log("x------------------x");
  console.log("x Servidor On-line x");
  console.log("x------------------x");
});`
```

Comment: O que você está usando para servir os arquivos? O problema está na configuração do servidor que "diz" que o arquivo de estilo é CSS e não HTML.

Comment: Então, eu fiz um servidor rapido com node:

var http = require('http').createServer(server);
var fs = require('fs');

function server(req, response){
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('view/index.html'));
};

http.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log("x------------------x");
  console.log("x Servidor On-line x");
  console.log("x------------------x");
});`

E é só isso...

Comment: @RafaelaCordeiro, não é a melhor opção fazer um servidor "rápido" com o módulo `http`. Você pode optar pelo `express` ou `http-server`. Dito isto, segue um "pequeno" código para  solucionar seu problema. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046869/9101590

Comment: Pode postar seu arquivo css por favor se não for muito grande.

Comment: O problema então está claramente no servidor que você criou. Use um servidor pronto para desenvolvimento - ou poste o código do seu servidor para que possa ser corrigido: é ali que está seu problema específico.

(você pode usar a linguagem python instalada no seu sistema para servir arquivos estáticos diretamente: `python3 -m http.server 4000` )

Answer (score 6):

Seu `MIME type` está errado, não é `type="text/html"` é `type="text/css"`

Assim ele não carrega:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="bootstrap.css">
```

O correto é assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
```

Uma dica é usar o `DevTools` do **Chrome** por exemplo para verificar se o arquivo `.CSS` carregou corretamente. No **Chrome** abra seu documento, aperte `F12`, vai na `Aba Network`, masque o `CSS` e depois de de um `F5`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então, eu já fiz isso. Lá eu expliquei: "coloquei: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> e continuava dando a mesma mensagem. Troquei para <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="bootstrap.css"> e a mensagem parou de dar no console, mas meus estilos não funcionam.

Comment: Iniciei um servidor node e pensei nisso estar dando algum conflito, peguei os arquivos (index e os css's) copiei para uma pasta vazia, abri no navegador e funcionou. Tem algo de errado por conta do servidor?

`var http = require('http').createServer(server);
var fs = require('fs');

function server(req, response){
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('view/index.html'));
};

http.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log("x------------------x");
  console.log("x Servidor On-line x");
  console.log("x------------------x");
});`

Comment: Talves seu server não reconhece esse MIME type...  Conferiu se o CSS está aparecendo na Aba Network? De Node eu não entendo nada...

Comment: Realmente, foi descuido, estava sem type,já adicionei e está aparecendo no network corretamente, mas não funciona o estilo mesmo assim.

Comment: Vi que esse problema tem muita tendência de ser problema relacionado ao servidor. Encontrei um caso semelhante no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see), dá uma olhada...

Comment: @AndréFilipe legal a referência parece que lá tem até uns truques pra tentar resolver usando `/` no path, ou `#`. Mas ai vou deixar pro autor da pergunta analisar... *O interessante foi ver que a outra resposta que derem aqui é **basicamente um plágio**, o cara traduziu o texto inteiro na cara dura e nem citou a fonte...*

Comment: @hugocsl, foi a primeira coisa que notei ao olhar as *respostas* daqui. Infelizmente ainda existem pessoas que querem tirar algum aproveito, mas não sabem que citar a fonte é tão útil quanto expandir o conhecimento.

Comment: @AndréFilipe e para piorar eu dei a dica pro cara, ele viu, comentou que era falta de atenção da parte dele e ainda assim não colocou a fonte.... Vai entender... :/

Comment: Além de alertá-lo você orientou sobre o fato. Acredito que ele já esteja ciente disso. Espero muito que seja leiguice!

Answer (score 0):

Opa então para você poder carregar um arquivo css de um diretório no Node.js você precisar primeiro determinar a pasta estática onde ficam esses arquivos, o que você pode fazer é o seguinte:

- Criar uma pasta na raiz do projeto chamada public
- Dentro dessa pasta public você coloca a pasta com os seus arquivos css

Dai no seu app.js você vai colocar o seguinte comando se você estiver utilizando o express

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```

E dentro do seu arquivo index html ao invés de ficar:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Vai ficar:

```
<link href="/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: E solucionei o caso, mas não usei o express, usei o angular http-server, e dai funcionou. Eu precisava mesmo adicionar um servidor. Eu ainda estou aprendendo Angular, então estou em busca de ver o melhor caminho ainda. Obrigada :)

Answer (score -1):

Vamos começar com a explicação:

Os navegadores fazem solicitações HTTP para servidores. O servidor então faz uma resposta HTTP.

Ambas as solicitações e respostas consistem em vários cabeçalhos e um corpo (às vezes opcional) com algum conteúdo.

Se houver um corpo, então um dos cabeçalhos é o `Content-Type` que descreve o que é o corpo (é um documento HTML? Uma imagem? O conteúdo de uma submissão de formulário? Etc.).

Quando você solicita sua folha de estilo, seu servidor está dizendo ao navegador que é um documento HTML (`Content-Type: text/html`) em vez de uma folha de estilo (`Content-Type: text/css`).

Mude de `Content-Type: text/html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="bootstrap.css">
```

para:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: Então, eu já fiz isso. Lá eu expliquei:
"coloquei: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> e continuava dando a mesma mensagem. 
Troquei para <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="bootstrap.css"> e a mensagem parou de dar no console, mas meus estilos não funcionam.

Comment: Iniciei um servidor node e pensei nisso estar dando algum conflito, peguei os arquivos (index e os css's) copiei para uma pasta vazia, abri no navegador e funcionou. Tem algo de errado por conta do servidor?

`var http = require('http').createServer(server);
var fs = require('fs');

function server(req, response){
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('view/index.html'));
};

http.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log("x------------------x");
  console.log("x Servidor On-line x");
  console.log("x------------------x");
});`

Comment: Amigo quando vc copiar a resposta do StackOverflow em inglês é interessante vc pelo menos citar a fonte. Pegar alguma resposta de lá não é problema, o que vc pode considerar ser ético ou não é citar a fonte de onde vc pegou a resposta! Não é um ataque pessoal ok, é só uma dica beleza. []´s

Comment: Beleza! Foi a falta de atenção. Obrigado